# Atom IDE Tab Groups

Tags: windows, macos, tabs, ide, atom-editor

I was a macbook user in my previous job.  I used Atom IDE as a text editor there because I liked how it handled projects in the LHS tree view, and because I liked the tabs.  In particular, I liked that in MacOSX, tabs could be grouped, so that clicking one group got one set of tabs, while hiding the other set of tabs.  This allowed me to have more tabs open (without tab name being too small to read), while at the same time being more organized.

**My question is:** is there a way to get the "tab group" feature when using Atom IDE in Windows 10?  My first guess is no, since the tab group was probably an OS feature, but I could be wrong.

NOTE: This is not in reference to a "pane", as that feature doesn't hide tabs, as I was hoping for in tab groups.

Answer (score 0):

**One Answer**: I found this ATOM ide package that makes the tab row into multiple rows.  However, instead of hiding one row and showing the other row, it shows both rows at the same time, stacked.  It works for now, but a full-fledged plugin for this would be nice.

https://atom.io/packages/multirow-tabs